# Download/Build OpenCV with pkg-config in Windows

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, pkg-config, meson-build

I am trying to download/build OpenCV to use a project with meson, but the pkg-config says it doesn't exist.

I used this example:
https://cv-tricks.com/how-to/installation-of-opencv-4-1-0-in-windows-10-from-source/

Using the guide I did the following steps:

1. I Used Cmake and chose the PKG-CONFIG argument option.
2. I Used Visual Studio to build the code.

When I use `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` or `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4` on CMD It doesn't find it.

The output:

```
Package opencv was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `opencv.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'opencv' found
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: OpenCV build files don't generate `opencv4.pc` when compiler is Visual Studio, even when `OPENCV_GENERATE_PKGCONFIG` is enabled: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.7.0/cmake/OpenCVGenPkgconfig.cmake#L1-L3

Comment: @SpacePotatoes Thanks! What should I do then? The meson requires the pkg-config of OpenCV.

Comment: Meson supports discovery of dependencies through CMake config files (https://mesonbuild.com/Dependencies.html#cmake), and OpenCV generates these files.